# Finding the component of a force perpendicular to a plane

Tags: vectors

I am trying to solve this particular question, however I am unsure how to go about it:

A plane has Cartesian equation $x + 2y + 3z = 4$.
A force $F$ acts on the plane, where $F = 2i − j + k$, and the units of F are Newtons.
Find the component of F normal to the plane.

From the Cartesian equation, I can obviously deduce that **n** is the vector ${\bf i}+2 {\bf j}+3 {\bf k}$, but I don't know where to go from here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is useful to use MathJax to format your equations

Comment: MathJax (basically same math commands as LaTeX typesetting) is good to learn. I helped you this time. If you want to you can see how it looks like by hitting "edit" button.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I will look into it for the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit normal to the plane is equal to $F = (1/\sqrt{14})(i + 2j + 3k)$.  The scalar component normal to the plane is just equal to the dot product of the Force vector with this unit normal.  If you need the vector component, the answer is this dot product times the unit normal to the plane.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is the [scalar projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Scalar_projection_and_first_properties) arising from the dot product.

Given two vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$, the component of $\vec u$ in the direction of $\vec v$ is
$$\vec u_{v} = (\vec u\cdot\vec v)\ \frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|}.$$